# Enable deep links in Google Play Console using github pages

Tags: github-pages, deep-linking, google-play-console

My website is https://timetap-app.github.io. When I go in Google Play Console to deep links, it automaticaly shows you a json to download and put in https://timetap-app.github.io/.well-known/assetlinks.json. I put it in the repo but when I try to verify it form GPC it says:

> Website association could not be created. Republish the JSON file and
> try again.

Is it because the domain points to .github.io and maybe it's trying to find it after .github? I remember having similar issue with the robots.txt.

Also, would be any problem exposing the sha256 in a public repo?

Comment: But that's not what the documentation says. I mean, it's a specific folder name